# Why does undefined is returned when an object returns a value

Tags: javascript

Trying to understand why is "undefined" returned when consoling out the output.

```
  var learnFn = (function(){


   var callMe = function(){
    console.log('hi');
   } 

   return {
     name:"tom",
     callMe: callMe
   }
  })();

  console.log(learnFn.callMe());

  Output:

  "hi"
  undefined
```

Comment: Because `cosole.log()` returns `undefined`. If you run this in the dev tools, you'd see exactly that.

Comment: @vlaz: That's not the reason. In the code above, it wouldn't matter what `console.log()` returns.

Comment: @MichaelGeary true, I didn't pay much attention to what the function was - I thought somebody was executing some code in the console and confused about `undefined` coming from `console.log`. Happens regularly enough to have fooled me.

Comment: @vlaz yes i was confused about undefined coming from console.log . Now got it, but how to get rid of it?

Comment: @godfreyfernandes don't log a function call that returns `undefined` or alternatively, do not return `undefined` from the function call you log the result of.

Answer (score 3):

The function you are calling:

> ```
> var callMe = function(){
>     console.log('hi');
> }
> ```

… has no `return` statement. So it returns `undefined` (which you then log, after the `console.log` statement *inside* that function has run).